# TwilioException {message: "31002: Connection Declined"} even though Call goes through

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Whenever I place an outbound call using Twilio I get "TwilioException {message: "31002: Connection Declined"}". However, the call goes through to my phone and I answer it and hear the default message. It seems to all work except I still get an error message. I went to Twilio console to look at the debugger. It says, "here was a network failure attempting to connect to this URL ### HTTP connection failure". But somehow it reaches '/voice' because I get the call on my phone.

```
"use strict";

require("dotenv-safe").load();
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const { urlencoded } = require("body-parser");
const twilio = require("twilio");
const ClientCapability = twilio.jwt.ClientCapability;
const VoiceResponse = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

let app = express();

// Generate a Twilio Client capability token
app.get("/token", (request, response) => {
  const capability = new ClientCapability({
    accountSid,
    authToken,
  });

  capability.addScope(
    new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
      applicationSid: process.env.TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID,
    })
  );

  const token = capability.toJwt();
  // Include token in a JSON response
  response.send({
    token: token,
  });
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/voice", (request) => {
  const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

  console.log(`## Making a call to ${request.body.number}##`);
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log("************************************");

  client.calls
    .create({
      url: "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
      from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
      to: request.body.number,
    })
    .then((call) => console.log(call.sid));});



let server = http.createServer(app);
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Express Server listening on *:${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am guessing that you are trying to place the call from [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) or the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk). While you do receive a call from Twilio to your phone that plays a demo message, I am guessing you intend to connect the browser/app to the phone call.

What is happening here is that you place the call in the client-side which causes Twilio to make a webhook request to the URL set in your TwiML app. That URL is your `/voice` endpoint which should respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) to tell Twilio what to do next with the call. Instead, your code never responds to this request, though it does use the REST API to generate a new call, the call you receive.

So, instead of placing a call with the REST API, we should return TwiML using [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) to connect the calls. Try the following instead:

```js
app.post("/voice", (request, response) => {
  const voiceResponse = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  console.log(`## Making a call to ${request.body.number}##`);
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log("************************************");

  voiceResponse.dial(request.body.number);

  response.setContentType("text/xml");
  response.send(voiceResponse.toString());
});
```

**Edit**

After a chat in the comments, it seems the goal here is not to make a call from the browser to another person, but just to trigger an outbound call. In this case, you don't need Twilio Client or to generate access tokens at all. You can just make an ajax request to your back-end to generate the call using the REST API.

On the back-end, this should work:

```js
app.post("/voice", (request, response) => {
  const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

  console.log(`## Making a call to ${request.body.number}##`);
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log("************************************");

  client.calls
    .create({
      url: "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
      from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
      to: request.body.number,
    })
    .then((call) => {
      console.log(call.sid);
      // return the CallSid to the front-end as proof of success
      response.json({ callSid: call.sid });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      response.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you! Seems to have fixed it. Just out of curiosity so I can understand this more. If I wanted to use the REST API instead what changes would have to be made to make that work?

Comment: Would you want to use the REST API to create a call and still connect it to the caller using the browser/app?

Comment: No it doesn’t need to connect them to the browser. Just needs to place an outbound call.

Comment: Ah, ok. Am I right that you have added Twilio Client to your front-end application here? If you just want to trigger calls, not have the person using the browser connect to those calls, then you likely don't need Twilio Client at all. You should be able to make a request directly from your front-end to your back-end that calls the REST API as you were doing originally. Your original endpoint didn't return anything, so would leave the request hanging, but I'll update my answer with an example of how to fix that.

Comment: Yes as of now I’m using twilio client on the front end. Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, if you don't actually want the user using the front-end to speak on the phone through the browser, then you don't need Twilio Client. Check my updated answer.